# "Gifting and Social Trading" Facebook Requests

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook has an example of adding a gifting loop to an app here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/

See "Gifting and Social Trading"

My question is how to check for incoming gift requests so that they can be displayed. All of the examples I have found require that you click on the incoming message within facebook in order to get the request into your app. But that's clearly not what they are demonstrating here.

How do I check for the incoming requests so that I can display them in an inbox *without* going through the facebook app?

I am guessing that the user in this example did not have to click on each request in the facebook app to get them to show up in their inbox.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/#apprequests

Comment: Can you put this down as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requests a user has received from your app you can be queried via `/me/apprequests`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/apprequests/